# Are there any older commentaries on Narada Bhakti Sutras?

Tags: vaishnavism, bhakti, narada, sutra, narada-bhakti-sutra

I want to study Narada Bhakti  Sutra.Are there any old and popular commentaries on the Narada Bhakti Sutra?